Understanding fictitious forces
My question is a little difficult to understand so I am using 2 images,

In the 1st image we can see that an block is kept at rest with respect to an inertial frame and we could say that net forces are zero, but in the 2nd case (of the first image) a man from non inertial frame is observing the same block so for the man the block looks to be moving towards him, so we have to add an pseudo force.
But if we come to rotational frame, that is our 2nd image

the small block is at rest on a large table at a distance R from (axis of rotation of disc without string or anything) with respect to an inertial frame it is at rest , but when Ram observes the same block it appears to be in rotation while the centrifugal force is in radial outward direction so the block had to be moving radially outward so why did it seem or not seem rotation to Ram,
Hope you understand how I tried to relate pseudo and centrifugal forces.
If I am wrong somewhere then please correct

Your question is open-ended. It will need focus to stay open on this site. Now for the topic, a person should only start attempting to play with fictitious effects when they have already mastered the fiction-less explanations and mathematically derive the fictitious effects from scratch. It is a source of endless confusion.

In your first example, there is a little mistake in your explanation:

so for the man the block looks to be moving towards him, so we have to add an pseudo force.

Even comparing inertial frames of reference, you can have one observer moving torwards the other without the need to add inertial forces - they can have relative velocities, just not relative accelerations.
In the case of acceleration, let us say that you have an object at the centre of a circled path being traversed by an observer. The frame of the observer is non-inertial when compared to the frame of the block. To make the curve, the frame of the observer will apply some centripetal force which, combined with its original velocity, will create a curved path. However the observer in this frame understands itself at rest so that, for it, there is no centripetal force being applied. Instead, it observes a centrifugal force pushing him away from the block. This force is fictitious, since what happens in practice is the inertial response of the observer to this centripetal acceleration. If the situation was, however, merely the two frames approaching one another at constant speeds, no fictitious force would appear.
